# extracting a wildfly client file not posiible ni docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to add keyCloak sub system for wildfly in a docker as bellow but the file can not be unziped and it gives me an error. I have tried the tar variant but no success either. Going to the url in curl from browser downloads the file and it can be extracted on my local machine (ubuntu 20.4).
Am I missing something in the Dockerfile?

```
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
  unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of keycloak-oidc-wildfly-adapter- 
  15.0.2.zip or
  keycloak-oidc-wildfly-adapter-15.0.2.zip.zip, and cannot find keycloak-oidc- 
  wildfly-adapter-15.0.2.zip.ZIP, period.
```

The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly:25.0.0.Final

ENV KEYCLOAK_VERSION 15.0.2
ENV WILDFLY_HOME /opt/jboss/wildfly

WORKDIR $WILDFLY_HOME
RUN curl -f -O https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/releases/download/15.0.2/keycloak-oidc-wildfly-adapter-15.0.2.zip \
&& unzip keycloak-oidc-wildfly-adapter-15.0.2.zip -d .
CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 9990
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that wget works just fine. I changed the curl options into -LO and it worked. It was a mutipart file.